# He Used the Gun

Tags: lateral-thinking

One day, a man was hunting. When he saw an animal, he fired his gun. Realizing his mistake, he had a few seconds to run, but was soon dead. What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He was in the arctic and caused an avalanche. The avalanche killed him.

Comment: I think this could be it! (FYI i don’t think you can post more than one answer, i’m not sure though)

Comment: @Midori I think it's just frowned upon not completely wrong

Answer (score 3):

I think is what has happened:

> The man was at war. He saw an enemy (the animal) and he fired, but missed the target,so he ran. His enemy didn’t make the same mistake.

Comment: The question said that he was hunting, not at war. :P

Comment: What is a war if not a big hunting party? See the lateral-thinking tag

Comment: Hmm... that is true.

Answer (score 3):

> He fired the bullet straight up, and a few seconds later it struck and killed him.

Comment: I don't think a falling bullet can kill you, but I may be wrong.

Comment: depends on how powerful the gun is...

Comment: wait this is pretty good :P +1

Comment: How exactly does he run away from a bullet falling from the sky? He has no idea where it's going to land. Also, this makes no sense if he's hunting, unless he has really really really bad aim

Comment: Maybe he was trying to shoot stright up, but his aim was *so bad* that the exact distance he ran just happened to match the deviation from the vertical and he got hit.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer:

> He shot an elephant with a low-caliber rifle. The elephant then charged at him and killed him.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps...

> He shot a cub and the mother bear killed him

Comment: This is why badly written lateral-thinking are so hilarious +1